# How to set path in azure-pipeline using prependpath

Tags: azure, azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines

I am trying to set path in an Azure-pipeline using prepend path

```
  echo '##vso[task.prependpath]$(HOME)/miniconda3/bin'
  echo "New path 1... $PATH"

  ##vso[task.prependpath]($HOME)/miniconda3/bin
  echo "New path 3... $PATH"

  ##vso[task.prependpath]($env.HOME)/miniconda3/bin
  echo "New path 3... $PATH"

  ##vso[task.prependpath]$(env.HOME)/miniconda3/bin
  echo "New path 4... $PATH"

  ##vso[task.prependpath]$(env.home)/miniconda3/bin
  echo "New path 5... $PATH"

  ##vso[task.prependpath]$(home)/miniconda3/bin
  echo "New path 6... $PATH"
```

None of this sets the path, but when doing `export PATH=$HOME/miniconda3/bin:$PATH` the path is set.

How to set `PATH` variable with `HOME` in azure-pipeline

[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From the [task.prepend docs](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/blob/master/docs/authoring/commands.md)

> The specified directory is prepended to the PATH. The updated environment variable will be reflected in subsequent tasks.

Referencing $PATH from subsequent tasks does the trick.

**Build Step 1**

```sh
echo '##vso[task.prependpath]$(HOME)/miniconda3/bin'
```

**Build Step 2**

```sh
echo "$PATH"'

## This prints /home/vsts/miniconda3/bin:/usr/share/rust/...and on it goes...
```

Comment: Understood. Thank you so much. It's literally not obvious to print it in the next step