# set PATH in azure pipelines in Windows

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, raku, rakudo

I am using Azure Pipelines to build a [Rakudo](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo) binary for Raku (previously aka Perl 6) in Windows.

This is my `azure-pipelines.yml` file:

```
jobs:
- job: Windows
  pool:
    vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'
  steps:
    - bash: |
        mkdir -p $(Build.SourcesDirectory)/rakudo-win
        curl -L https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/releases/download/2019.07.1/rakudo-2019.07.1.tar.gz | tar xz
        mv rakudo-2019.07.1 rakudo
        cd rakudo
        C:/Strawberry/perl/bin/perl Configure.pl --gen-moar --gen-nqp --backends=moar --prefix=$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/rakudo-win
        make
        make install

    - bash: |
        echo "##vso[task.prependpath]$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/rakudo-win/bin"

    - bash: |
        perl6 -v
```

The pipeline script builds `perl6` binary fine inside `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/rakudo-win/bin` folder. There is indeed `perl6.exe` inside `$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/rakudo-win/bin`.  To make it available, I set the path by prepending it in the bash script. But when I try to run command `perl6 -v`, the build fails at this step.

I searched for similar issues in SO [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57322531/how-to-set-path-in-azure-pipeline-using-prependpath), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53857085/change-current-working-directory-in-azure-pipelines), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49288558/set-path-environment-variable-during-vsts-build-so-it-would-persist-across-bui?rq=1).

Still I could not solve my issue. Any help how to make `perl6` binary available at `PATH`?

**EDITED**

Next thing I did was create another `.yml` script as follows:

```
jobs:
- job: Windows
  pool:
    vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'
  steps:
    - script: |
        call "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Enterprise\VC\Auxiliary\Build\vcvars64.bat"
    - pwsh: |
        mkdir -p C:\rakudo-win
        Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/releases/download/2019.07.1/rakudo-2019.07.1.tar.gz" -OutFile "rakudo.tar.gz"
        tar -xvf .\rakudo.tar.gz
        cd rakudo-2019.07.1
        C:\Strawberry\perl\bin\perl Configure.pl --gen-moar --gen-nqp --backends=moar --prefix=C:\rakudo-win
        make
        make install
    - pwsh: |
        $oldpath = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH).path
        $newpath = "C:\rakudo-win\bin;$oldpath" 
        Set-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH -Value $newpath
    - script: |
        SET PATH=C:\rakudo-win\bin;%PATH%

    - script: |
        perl6 -v
```

**and tried changing PATH** twice once in powershell and another in cmdline. But still it throws following error:

```
'perl6' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Any help?

Comment: This is just a linear list of commands, why not use a batch file?

Comment: I'm not sure, but I think on Win, the directory MUST be `c:\rakudo`. At least that used to be the case.

Comment: Yes I can set the directory as `c:\rakudo`, in that case I need to have `C:\rakudo\bin` in `PATH`, so that I can use `perl6` in subsequent downstream `script`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In fact, you are very close to the correct solution. Your second powershell task has set the PATH successfully. You can add another separate task to print out the system `PATH` value to verify this.

```
- pwsh: |
    $NewPathInRegistry = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH).path
    Write-Host $NewPathInRegistry
```

[image]

---

To set the `PATH` programmatically, you can not use `set` command, this command can indeed set the environment variable `PATH`, but the **disadvantage** of `set` is the new `PATH` value is only available in the current command line terminal, it does not actually been added into the **System Variable**. That's why you were getting an unrecognized error in the next `script` step.

To permanently add the directory to environment variable `PATH` so that it can work for next others steps, you need use `setx` or add them into **Registry** by using `reg add`. But the usage of setx has limitation that the `PATH` value max to 1024 characters. So, here the best solution is updating `PATH` by modifying the Registry value.

BUT, updating Registry still has another issue, you must kill current process and run one new process to run `perl6` so that it can read the new available Registry setting.

If run `stop-process` in Azure devops pipeline, it will make the task failed with exit code **-1**. This is the expected exit code, so you can set the `continueOnError: true` to step so that the next steps can continue.

Answer (score 12):

The best method I have found for setting the PATH for subsequent tasks in Azure Pipelines is by using the logging command syntax mentioned in the [first of the three SO links](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57322531/how-to-set-path-in-azure-pipeline-using-prependpath) you looked at. Since you are using PowerShell in your updated yaml pipeline, the command would be:

```
Write-Host "##vso[task.prependpath]$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/rakudo-win/bin"
```

Note that this only applies to *subsequent* tasks, if you try outputting the PATH variable in the current task it will not have updated.

Answer (score 1):

why not just do this:

```
- script: |
  PATH=$BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY/rakudo-win/bin:$PATH perl6 -v
```

Comment: Once `perl6` is in PATH, I want to run these commands:   git clone https://github.com/ugexe/zef.git, cd zef, perl6 -I. bin/zef install .

Comment: then you could set path with `export PATH=$BUILD_SOURCESDIRECTORY/rakudo-win/bin:$PATH` and run those commands

Comment: Sorry its not working. The error that it throws with last script in my `.yml` is `/d/a/_temp/bd6b25db-74ec-40a1-90f3-0d0ef477f3df.sh: line 1: perl6: command not found`.