# How to install Az module on Windows Server through DevOps?

Tags: azure, powershell, asp.net-core, .net-core, azure-devops

I am writing a .Net Core application and in one of the APIs, I have to execute the PS script. Earlier I was using AzureRm commands in my PS script along with .Net Framework which use to work just fine, but after upgrading to .Net Core this script is failing. I updated my PS script to use Az commands but post that am getting an error while executing this script through the API.

Error:

> The specified module 'Az' was not loaded because no valid module file
> was found in any module directory

DevOps Powershell Script to install Az module:

```
Install-Module -Name Az -RequiredVersion 2.8.0 -Force -AllowClobber 

Get-InstalledModule #Just print out the details to confirm whether `Az 2.8.0` has been installed successfully

// Even setting PSModulePath is not working

$key = (Get-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager').OpenSubKey('Environment', $true)
$path = $key.GetValue('PSModulePath','','DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames')
$path += ';D:\Program Files (x86)\ManagedDependencies\PowerShell\AzPSModules\1.0.0'
$key.SetValue('PSModulePath',$path,[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::ExpandString)
```

Is there anything else that I need to add to make sure that I can execute Az command in PS script from Azure App Service APIs?

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to install and set the **ModulePath** by using  PowerShell. I am able to Set the **ModulePath** in the ***Environment variable***.

#### The workaround follows

```
# installing the Required Module
Install-Module -Name Az -RequiredVersion 2.8.0 -Force -AllowClobber -SkipPublisherCheck
# here you can get the list of installed Module
Get-InstalledModule 
# Set the custom path of PSModulePath in Environment Variable
$key = (Get-Item 'HKLM:\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager').OpenSubKey('Environment', $true)
$path = $key.GetValue('PSModulePath','','DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames')
$path += ';D:\Program Files (x86)\ManagedDependencies\PowerShell\AzPSModules\1.0.0'
$key.SetValue('PSModulePath',$path,[Microsoft.Win32.RegistryValueKind]::ExpandString)
```

[image]

> The specified module 'Az' was not loaded because no valid module file was found in any module directory

**We cannot import all the `Az-Modules` from the  Az folder because `Sub-Modules` are not installed in the system path. we can load these `Sub-Modules` one by one.**

> The sub-modules are automatically being searched in the system path. As they are actually installed in another path, the PowerShell cannot find them, which causes errors. Refer [Github discussion](https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues/13406#issuecomment-722937044) for more information

### Updated Answer

use the **Get-ItemProperty** to set the environment path in hosted Agent

```yaml
# Here using this property in a pipeline
- pwsh: |
    $NewPathRegistory = (Get-ItemProperty -Path 'Registry::HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\System\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment' -Name PATH).path
    Write-Host $NewPathRegistry
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61246746/15997690)

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I believe that you have executed these commands on your local machine? If so, then the same I am also able to do so but the issue is that I am not able to set the path on the hosted agent. Is there any way to do this via build pipeline?

Comment: Please check the updated Answer